# print dictionary keys and values in ordered manner

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with keys and values as shown below.

```
from datetime import datetime
dic = {'pack1':'stage1','pack2':'stage2','pack3':'stage3','pack4':'stage4'}
```

I want to print the keys and their corresponding values in ordered manner in new line, like

Update at 2018-09-18 09:58:03.263575

```
**Delivery**           **State** 

'pack1'                 'stage1'

'pack2'                 'stage2'

'pack3'                 'stage3'

'pack4'                 'stage4'
```

The code I tried is given below

```
print("Update at %s\nDelivery\t\t\t\t\t\t\tState \n{}\t\t\t{}".format({key for key in dic.keys()}, {val for val in dic.values()}) %datetime.now())
```

But it give the output as

Update at 2018-09-18 09:58:03.263575

```
**Delivery**                                          **State** 

set(['pack4', 'pack1', 'pack2', 'pack3'])           set(['stage1', 'stage2', 'stage3', 'stage4'])
```

The values doesn't correspond to their keys, and the output is given in a single line as a set of lists. How to format the output as my requirement?
(There are whitespaces between 'delivery' and State but stack overflow doesn't show them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dictionaries: How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/dictionaries-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary order is not preserved by default. If you want that for any reason then you need to use OrderedDict  instead

Comment: Note: As of 3.6, CPython 3.6 preserves it as an implementation detail; in 3.7, it's preserved as a language guarantee in all Python interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to note that since Python 3.7, a `dict` preserves the order in which data is entered. Prior to that, you can use an `OrderedDict`.

Although, it seems what you want is to sort the key-value pairs in alphabetical order of keys. In that case, you can use `sorted`.

```
dic = {'pack1': 'stage1', 'pack2': 'stage2', 'pack3': 'stage3', 'pack4': 'stage4'}

for k, v in sorted(dic.items()):
    print (k + '\t' + v)
```

### Output

```
pack1    stage1
pack2    stage2
pack3    stage3
pack4    stage4
```

From there you can work on the printing format.

Comment: The OP appears to be primarily using Python 2.7 (the `set` repr is `set([...])`, not `{...}`), so you'd need to fix the `print` to be compatible (or add a `__future__` import).

Comment: @ShadowRanger there

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over your input, you can't do this cleanly in a single `format` and `print` operation.

If the keys only need to match their values, just do:

```
dic = {'pack1':'stage1','pack2':'stage2','pack3':'stage3','pack4':'stage4'}

for k, v in dic.items():  # .viewitems() on Python 2.7
    print("{}\t\t\t{}".format(k, v))
```

If you need the output ordered, not just matched up, `dict` don't provide that guarantee before 3.7 (and don't provide even implementation dependent guarantees until 3.6). You'd need a `collections.OrderedDict`. You could do a presort though:

```
for k, v in sorted(dic.items()):  # .viewitems() on Python 2.7
    print("{}\t\t\t{}".format(k, v))
```

so the output ordering is predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like:

```
dic = {'pack1':'stage1','pack2':'stage2','pack3':'stage3','pack4':'stage4'}
print('Delivery\t\tState')
for i in dic.items():
   print(('\t'*3).join(i))
```

Dictionaries are not ordered under python 3.6, so `OrderdDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dic = OrderedDict([('pack1', 'stage1'), ('pack2', 'stage2'), ('pack3', 'stage3'), ('pack4', 'stage4')])
print('Delivery\t\tState')
for i in dic.items():
   print(('\t'*3).join(i))
```

All Outputs:

```
Delivery        State
pack1           stage1
pack2           stage2
pack3           stage3
pack4           stage4
```